# Any positive integer can be written as sum / difference of consecutive squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

How should one go about proving that $x \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written (with the right combination of signs) as $\pm 1^2 \pm 2^2 \pm \ldots \pm n^2$ for any $x : x, n \in \mathbb N$? I have tried for hours but can't figure out an appropriate approach. So what I ask of you specifically is, how should one be able to determine a reasonable approach for such a conjecture? Thanks.

Comment: I would think that one can restrict oneself to $x > 0$ since for $-x$ on just flips the signs. And then induction. Also, one could maybe argue that the function $S(j, i) := \sum_{k=j}^{i} k^2 = 1/6 (i - j + 1) (2 i^2 + 2 i j + i + j (2 j - 1))$ is surjective.

Comment: For odd numbers, it's trivial $2n+1 = (n+1)^2 - n^2$. For even $2n = (n+1)^2 - n^2-1^2$

Comment: @rtybase For even numbers and $n = 1$, you have the summand $1^2$ twice so its not in the form the op asked.

Comment: For every pair of positive integers $(x,m)$, there is an $n$ such that $x = \pm 1^m \pm 2^m \pm 3^m \pm \cdots \pm n^m$. See [Finding the min of $m$ such that $k = \pm 1^n \pm 2^n \pm 3^n \pm \cdots \pm m^n$ for a given pair $(n,k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566663/finding-the-min-of-m-such-that-k-pm-1n-pm-2n-pm-3n-pm-cdots-pm-mn).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $P(m)$ be the statement that $m \in \Bbb{N}$ can be represented as the sum of squares with appropriate signs. We induct on $m$. For the **base cases,** we have
\begin{align*}
P(1):\quad 1 & = 1^2,\\
P(2):\quad 2 & = −1^2 − 2^2 − 3^2 + 4^2,\\
P(3):\quad 3 & = −1^2 + 2^2,\\
P(4):\quad 4 & = −1^2 − 2^2 + 3^2.
\end{align*}
Note the following is true.
$$m^2 − (m + 1)^2 − (m + 2)^2 + (m + 3)^2 = 4.$$

Using this, for the inductive step we can now show that $P(m) \implies P(\color{red}{m+4})$. Because if $P(m)$ is true, then $m$ has a representation and in that representation we just need to add a few terms using the above identity to get the representation for $m+4$.

So we have, $P(1) \implies P(5), P(2) \implies P(6), P(3) \implies P(7), P(4) \implies P(8), \ldots$

Comment: @ Anurag A
P(4) : why didn't you write $4=2^2$ ? By the way, maybe it would be clearer to use another symbol than $m$ itself in the induction step. For example, if we know that $2=-1^2-2^2-3^3+4^2$, then we see that $6=-1^2-2^2-3^3+4^2+4$ and replace the last term by $5^2-6^2-7^2+8^2$ (hence using $m=5$ and not $m=2$).

Comment: Another question would be to find, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a decomposition in a *minimal* number of terms. I don't know how to get this, unless using brute force computation...

Comment: I answer to my own question in the pre-previous comment : $4=2^2$ is not pertinent in the context since it is asked to start from 1.

Comment: @Adren Every positive integer number is a sum of $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ squares.

Comment: @ajotatxe : I do know that, but we are talking about *consecutive* squares :)